# Scriptlets and EL rendering as text in JSP(not compiled)

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have a problem with including tag libs and expression language in JSP page. Java don't want compile that and understand that like html text. For example if jsp content

```
 <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%> <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

it will be the same like in browser. What i am doing wrong? Mb someone had that problem.

Comment: Where did you place your .jsp file? Do you use Tomcat? What did you type in browser's address bar?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `web.xml`, it should contain the following configuration.

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
        <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

The compiler won't compile the code that has scriptlets like `<%`, `<%!`, `<%=`, `%>` if you has set `<scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>`.